# Ruby on Rails grabbing Yahoo contacts on "Contacts" gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, contacts, import-contacts

I installed "contacts" gem on my local machine, wrote some code to get yahoo, gmail and hotmail contacts, and it was running smoothly. I moved the code to a server for testing, my gmail and hotmail contacts were still running, but Yahoo gave me the following error:

```
Contacts::AuthenticationError: Username and password do not match
```

I am sure that email and password are correct. I tried my code on another server the behavior was the same ...

Any hints?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of contacts gem?

Comment: I also have this issue in my application. I can successfully fetch contacts from Gmail but Yahoo! is creating problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Yahoo contacts uses Oauth, not BBauth: https://github.com/mislav/contacts/issues/4

The [turingstudio version of the gem](https://github.com/turingstudio/contacts) is more up to date and [it seems to support Yahoo Oauth](https://github.com/turingstudio/contacts/commit/680db599b521d7f0ada451649a2e28f2c7913c53).

Install it using bundler:

```
gem "turing-contacts", :git => "git://github.com/turingstudio/contacts.git"
```

Comment: The gem source above does not work.  This works: gem "turing-contacts", :git => "https://github.com/turingstudio/contacts.git"